# Why the Facebook Graph API doesn't return all public information available on a persons profile

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am wondering why for certain profiles I can access only a subset of the public information available on their profile.

For example, using the graph API explorer tool and requesting an access token with only basic permissions:

searching for john.street.10420 returns the user's full about information including hometown work etc. This matches what is available on his public profile by accessing the page https://www.facebook.com/john.street.10420.

However:

searching for angela.wright.1481(found using the facebook public profiles directory) returns only basic information even though there is public 'about' information available by accessing her profile: https://www.facebook.com/angela.wright.1481

Does anyone know why the graph API seems to be returning all the public information for some users but not others?

Comment: the behaviour is different today (4 years later) , https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/100006339102479?fields=about%2Chometown&access_token=access_token_sanitized (with the correct token) doesn't return infos