# Graph Api sometimes returns more information for "same" public user information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

If we have 2 Facebook users (u1 and u2) that both have several public information (about, working, etc) using a web browser.
Using a user access token from an User "u3" (different from u1 and u2), there are certain users (like u1) that returns in the graph api ALL this public information about him, however even when user "u2" (using the web browser just like u1) has the same public information, this one is not returned, eve more, only basic data is returned.

In brefing : graph.facebook.com/u1?accesstoken=u3AccessToken, returns ALL public information from u1

However graph.facebook.com/u2?accesstoken=u3AccessToken, returns ONLY basic information from u2, when u1 and u2 have the same public attributes for loged in users.

So, is there any internal user by user configuration that forbids to obtain public information from the api? (i do not see any other explanation..).

Edit: no, U1 U2 AND U3 have no relation at all (at least in friendship).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the exact question with examples you can use to check it by your self!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748887/why-the-facebook-graph-api-doesnt-return-all-public-information-available-on-a